# ipv6 socket_programming python

Tags: python, sockets, ipv6

i am trying to run this simple code to make client - server connection
this is server_side :

```
   from socket import *
   s = socket(AF_INET6 , SOCK_STREAM  , 0)
   s.bind(("127.0.0.1" , 1234  , 0 , 0))
```

but i got error

what should i do ?
thanks.

Comment: Post the entire error message. You're ignoring very valuable information.

Comment: How is this related to ipv6?

Comment: @Klaus OP is creating an `AF_INET6` socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`127.0.0.1` is an IPv4 address. It is not valid for AF_INET6.

Try

```
s.bind(("::1" , 1234))
```

Comment: well but why invalid ?

Comment: Read about the differences between IPv4 and IPv6. The address sizes and formats are different. You can't create an IPv6 socket and then try to use an IPv4 address.